# SyntaxError on importing named export in Node.js app when deploying to Render.com

Tags: node.js, import, export, es6-modules, render.com

I'm deploying a Node.js application to Render.com and encountered a SyntaxError during the deployment process. The error occurs when trying to import a named export from a module. Here's the specific error message I received during deployment:
⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️⬇️

```
> node backend/server.js
file:///opt/render/project/src/backend/controllers/message.controller.js:3
import { getReceiverSocketId, io } from "../socket/socket.js";
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module '../socket/socket.js' does not provide an export named 'getReceiverSocketId'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:132:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:214:5)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12)
Node.js v20.11.1
```

More Details:
This error does not occur when running the application locally, only during the deployment process on Render.com. I have verified that the getReceiverSocketId function is indeed exported in socket.js and the relative import path seems correct. Here's a simplified version of my socket.js module for context:

```
// socket.js
export const getReceiverSocketId = (receiverId) => {
    // Function implementation...
};
```

And here's how I'm importing it in message.controller.js:

```
// message.controller.js
import { getReceiverSocketId, io } from "../socket/socket.js";
```

What I've tried:
I've double-checked the export and import statements for typos.
I've ensured that the file paths are correct relative to the files that are importing them.
I've tried rebuilding the project to ensure that the latest changes are included in the deployment.
Expected Behavior:
I expected the deployment to succeed without import/export errors, as the application runs without issues locally.

Actual Behavior:
The deployment fails with the mentioned SyntaxError related to the import statement.

Question:
How can I resolve this SyntaxError during deployment when the local development environment does not show any issues with the same import/export statements?